# Always display a group of data first, and then order the rest by one of column

Tags: sql

I have a table  with 3 fields, let us say field1, field2, and field3. The value in field2 is either 0 or 1.

I am trying to fetch field1 in a way to always have all the rows where the value is 1 in field2 displayed first and arranged by field3, and then display the rest of data, also arranged by field3.

My research told me one can order by two fields, let us say 'Order by field2 Desc, field 3' but this really is not giving the expected result. Any  idea?

Comment: Share your complete sql query

Comment: @MarkByers I think order by is same for all currently used databases using sql. Do you know about any difference? Order by field2 desc,field3 should not be wrong in any database and version. Can it be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One small change is required for MySQL:

```
ORDER BY field2 = 1 DESC, field3
```

Or for standard SQL:

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN field2 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END DESC, field3
```

Comment: I am using MySQL 5.5.16 and this is exactly what I am looking for. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
order by 
case when field2=1 then 0 else 1 end,
     field3
```